# Auto-Execute a program on power up

Tags: boot

So, I put my Pi on a custom quadcopter. I have a program that will track an object with a cam and send out pulse widths to control my motors. Anyway, right now I have to ssh into my Pi to run my executable. I am using a WiFi dongle to connect with ssh, but that thing is sucking a lot of current, so I need to get rid of it. I would like it to run my makefile executable on power up, instead of having to ssh in and run it each time I want to fly. I already have the Pi auto-logging in. The makefile is compiled and ready to go with `sudo ./MyProg`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your command into the `/etc/rc.local` file. You don't have to use sudo because this file is run by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) at boot time.

If you encounter problems doing this, see:

- [Log output of background or boot script](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538)

If the program is persistent (i.e., keeps on ticking) **be certain to background it**.  If it does not have such a feature built in, use `&` at the end of the line.  If you do not do this, likely your boot will snag for a bit then init will kill the process.

Comment: Beware that if the command is persistent (i.e., it is going to run for more than a moment) you should use `command &` -- the `&` will fork it into the background properly.  For troubleshooting: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40493/log-output-of-system-script

Comment: @goldilocks What command would I use and how can I edit this file?

Comment: @Human The command would be the path to the program you want to run, e.g., `/home/pi/myprogram.py &`.  The file requires root permission to edit, try `sudo [editor] rc.local` where "[editor]" is whatever editor you want to use.

Comment: What would be a great editor for a noob like me? (Just want to do simple editing)

Comment: A lot of people use `nano` for stuff like this; it works without a GUI and is already installed.

Comment: @goldilocks Is there a GUI one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34778/discussion-between-human-and-goldilocks).

Answer (score 1):

You can just run `sudo crontab -e` and add the `@reboot` prefix to the command. For example if you wanted to run `bash /home/pi/script.sh` on boot, simply add `@reboot bash /home/pi/script.sh` to the end of your crontab file. Remember that crontab is user specific and may require sudo and a full path of execution.

Comment: If his program needs `sudo` privileges then the command needs to be `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: Yes, but once in the file it will not be necessary to add it again to your command as the crontab is already running it as root.

Comment: @jeffesc `crontab` does not run as `root`, that is why there is a user (`-u`) parameter. `sudo` doesn't need to be in the `crontab` file. He just needs to edit `root`'s `crontab` file with `sudo crontab -e`. If he entered `crontab -e` he would only edit his user's `crontab` file.

Comment: @PatrickCook I was referring that crontab is executed as root when adding appending sudo to it.

Answer (score 1):

For starting programs at boot time, another solution is to use `systemd`.   This has the advantage of starting and stopping the program as well as just start on boot.   A sample video tutorial illustrating how to use systemd is available here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEuViHanjKI

There are also many other resources available by searching on "systemd".

Comment: **BE WARNED** this solution only works on **Raspbian Jessie**. As `systemd` was introduced in that flavor. This question was posted in 2014, and Jessie released in 2015, so it's fair to assume the OP was using Raspbian Wheezy. Though, if you are using Jessie, **this is the best solution.**